# Upper bound of Logarithmic Integral

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove that

$$ \int_2^{\sqrt{x}}{\frac{dt}{\log{t}}} + \int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}{\frac{dt} {\log{t}}} \le \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log{2}}+\frac{x-\sqrt{x}}{\log{\sqrt{x}}}$$

But I do not know how to start. Can you give me any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of the graph of $1/\log t$ then you can see that each integral is bounded by the area of the rectangle whose base is the interval of integration, and whose height is value of the function at the left end.  So the first integral is less than $$\frac{1}{\log 2} (\sqrt{x}-2)\leq \frac{1}{\log 2} (\sqrt{x})$$ (I'm assuming $x\geq 4$).  The other integral is handled the same way.